# Problemas com formulário ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Bom pessoal, estou com muita dificuldade para validar essa página em ajax, Creio que o problema esteja no arquivo da conexão do php, pesquisei em inumeros formularios mas não queria algo tão complexo ou com tantas validações, só algo simples, vou postar os arquivos, quando eu clico em entrar ele continua me levando para pagina do php, ao inves de fazer tudo em segundo plano sem recarregar, e as mensagens de erro/sucesso também não aparecem na div "#error".

login.js

```js
$('document').ready(function(){

 $("#entrar").click(function(){
  var data = $("#form").serialize();
   
  $.ajax({
   type : 'POST',
   url  : 'login.php',
   data : data,
   dataType: 'json',
   beforeSend: function()
   { 
    $("#entrar").html('Validando ...');
    
    
   },
   success:function(response){      
    if(response.codigo == "1"){ 
     $("#entrar").html('Entrar');
     $("#error").html('ACESSO PERMITIDO')
     setTimeout(' window.location.href = "index.php"; ',4000);
    }
    else{   
     $("#entrar").html('Entrar');
     $("#error").html('<strong>Usuario e/ou senha incorreto </strong>');
    }
      }
   
  });
 
 });

});
```

```html
<html>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="login.js"></script> 
<body>

<div id="error"></div>
<form id="form" method="post" action="login.php">
<center> <input class=borda name="login" type="text" required="true" class="form-group" id="login" placeholder="Usuário" title="Informe o usuário."/></center>
<br>
<center><input class=borda name="senha" type="password" id="senha" class="txt-form-control" placeholder="*****" required="true" title="Informe a senha."></center>
 
       
<center>
  <p>
<input type="submit" name="entrar" id="entrar" onclick=""  value="ENTRAR">
    
   </p>
  <p><a href="cadastro.php">Cadastre-se</a> </p>

</center>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

```
 <?php 
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $entrar = $_POST['entrar'];
    $senha = md5($_POST['senha']);
    $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','root', 'db_test');
    $db = mysql_select_db('db_test');
        if (isset($entrar)) {

    //Consulta no banco de dados
  $sql="select * from usuario where login='".$login."' and senha='".$senha."'"; 
  $resultados = mysql_query($sql)or die (mysql_error());
  $res=mysql_fetch_array($resultados); 

    // Se login e senha estiverem certos 

 if (@mysql_num_rows($resultados) !== 0){
        $retorno = array('codigo' => '1');
        if(!isset($_SESSION))   
        session_start();
        header("Location: success.php");    
        $_SESSION['nomeUsuario']=$res['login'];
        echo json_encode($retorno);
    }else{
        $retorno = array('codigo' => '0');
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();


        exit;   
}
        }

?>
```

Comment: Já tentou usar o event.preventDefault() ?

Answer (score 0):

Você está submetendo o formulário mesmo sem o Ajax, porque você setou o atributo método como POST, e o action!

Tente remover esses atributos do seu formulário e veja se funciona, se não funcionar, avise-nos!

Outra coisa, já testou se esse seu código tem vulnerabilidades? Você poderia experimentar o Php Login Minimal, um bom script para sistemas de login!

- **PhP Login Minimal:** https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal

**Atualização:**

Lembrei de uma gambiarra.
Tente remover o botão do tipo submit, esse botão sempre que clicado vai tentar submeter o formulário! Crie um botão fora da tag `<form>` e crie um evento em jQuery para quando ele for clicado!

Comment: Retirei o method e o action, ainda assim não funcionou.. mais alguma sugestão? Quanto ao Php Login Minimal é bem interessante! Mas este script em questão é meio que uma tarefa que tenho que realizar.

Comment: Entendo perfeitamente amigo, foi só uma outra sugestão kk!

Comment: `<form id="form" method="post" action="login.php" onsubmit="return false">` deve resolver, apesar de ser meio feio.

Comment: Nada ainda galera :/ Será que o problema é no arquivo html mesmo?